# Did the makers of HIMYM cast this actress on purpose to play Karen based on this quote?

Tags: casting, how-i-met-your-mother, that-70s-show

In the ***That '70s Show*** episode S05E06 [Over the Hills and Far Away](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0720141/) Eric says to Donna:

> You love Marquette and I've made my peace with that so we're just gonna go to different colleges, drift away and make out with guys named Ted because these are things we can't change, you're gonna get menopause and I'm gonna die!

He mentioned "guys named **TED**".

In ***How I Met Your Mother*** Ted has a college girlfriend named [Karen](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/Karen), who is played by the same actress as [Donna](http://that70sshow.wikia.com/wiki/Donna_Pinciotti).

I know the timeline doesn't match (Ted was born [April 25, 1978](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/Ted_Mosby)) and that the episodes aired 6 years and a half apart (19 nov 2002 for [Over the Hills and Far Away](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0720141/) and 9 march 2009 for [Sorry, Bro](http://how-i-met-your-mother.wikia.com/wiki/Sorry,_Bro)).

But did the makers of either *That '70s Show* or *How I Met Your Mother* do this on purpose?

It seems more logical that the HIMYM writers casted Laura based on the quote then the quote being written for a series that didn't even exist yet.

Comment: I guess not. I think that if they were doing it on purpose they would have called the character Donna too.

Comment: @JM dead link? .